# I am trying to change the name of the app(title)

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to change the title, there is no strings.xml. I changed the label, but it doesnot appear on the app. Pleae help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should just add

```
android:label="@string/app_name_full"
```

in **acticity** tag

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should I add this to AndroidManifest.xml ? Please note there is no string file in the app.